# Capturar la hora y fecha de modificación en Posgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy intentando capturar los datos de la hora y la fecha en una tabla postgresql. Obviamente quiero que cambie solo los registros modificados, pero con este disparador cambia toda la tabla. Soy novato, gracias.

```
create or replace function sp_capturarfecha() returns Trigger as $$ begin

if new.respuesta <> old.respuesta then

    update ediciondiaria set fecha_resp = current_timestamp; end if; return new; end $$ Language plpgsql;

create trigger TR_capturarfecha after update on ediciondiaria for each row when (old.respuesta <> new.respuesta) execute procedure sp_capturarfecha();
```

Comment: Pues es sencillo, amigo: ponerle WHERE al UPDATE.

Comment: le puse where new.respuesta != old.respuesta con el mismo resultado. Se actualiza toda.

Comment: ¿Cómo escoges qué filas se van a actualizar? Una vez que tengas esa respuesta, úsalo en tu where como condición, de esa forma sólo se actualizará ese registro...

Comment: Que la condición esté mal planteada no significa que haya que quitar el where, amigo